# How to do a random number or timestamp using link-to and query-params?

Tags: ember.js

I've got a simple route that should refresh when a query-param is updated

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        refresh: {
            refreshModel: true
        }
    }
});
```

Because this value needs to change for the refresh to work (in the above route) I need the value in my template to be random/new each time the page is rendered. Currently I'm trying to pass the link-to a random date value like so

```
{{#link-to "foo" (query-params refresh=new Date().toISOString())}}home{{/link-to}}
```

I've even tried creating a hbs helper that will return something template friendly but I can't seem to use that in the query-params link-to placeholder.

Anyone know a way to be pure template driven and add a random number or date value for the query-param? Or even better :) I'd just like to refresh regardless of the value being updated

Answer (score 1):

you can have in your controller a computed property like:

```
randomNumber: function(){
 return new Date().toISOString();
}.property()
```

and then in your template:

```
{{#link-to "foo" (query-params refresh=randomNumber)}}home{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: thanks but I was looking for a pure template driven approach (no computed in the controller / etc)